# SharePoint CSOM: how to get login name using email

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, user-profile-service

I have a column of type People in a SharePoint list. I want to get the user properties for the users present in that column.

For this I am using below code:

`PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor("ACCOUNT_NAME");`

Now the problem is that the user column gives the email id of the user, which if I pass to above code then it returns null:
[image]

So how can I get **Account Name** from email or is there any other alternative way to get the PersonProperties.

**NOTE:** User column shows Name(with presence) and is not allowed to change

**Update**

```
PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
            PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor("email_ID");
            context.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: added code snippet.

Comment: context.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties,p.DisplayName); try this and check

Comment: :( didn't work, actually problem is related to data passed to `GetPropertiesFor` method, it should be login name or account name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.ResolvePrincipal method. For example:

```
        Web web = context.Web;
        string email = "emailaddress@yourdomain.com";
        PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
        ClientResult<PrincipalInfo> principal = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(context, web, email, PrincipalType.User, PrincipalSource.All, web.SiteUsers, true);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then to get the login name from the resulting principal (if found), and get the user properties

```
        if (principal.Value != null)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Found user. LoginName is: '" + principal.Value.LoginName + "'");
            PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(principal.Value.LoginName);
            context.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("User with email '" + email + "' not found.");
        }
```

See MSDN for the ResolvePrincipal  method documentation: [Utility.ResolvePrincipal method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility.resolveprincipal.aspx). Full code example:

```
        Web web = context.Web;
        string email = "emailaddress@yourdomain.com";
        PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
        ClientResult<PrincipalInfo> principal = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(context, web, email, PrincipalType.User, PrincipalSource.All, web.SiteUsers, true);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        if (principal.Value != null)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Found user. LoginName is: '" + principal.Value.LoginName + "'");
            PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(principal.Value.LoginName);
            context.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("User with email '" + email + "' not found.");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Kevins. It seems like there is no direct way to .... have to call executeQuery at least two times.